# Android Layout button partially appears

Tags: android

So,

I have an activity with a layout, and in this layout I only have one button.

when clicking this button, the activity sets the visibility of the button to invisible, and launches a popup window.

I implemented a simple `onDismiss` function in this popup, which sets the button to visible

```
pw.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            MainActivity.packButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

the problem is that sometimes, not very often,  after the popup is dismissed, the button is shown, but only the top part of it, something like 1/5 of the button.

- I suspected that the button became visible before the popup dismissed completely, and a sort of a clash happened between them, but on the other hand I made some checks and the popup window and the button are able to be shown at the same time without a problem, so a "layout clash" cannot be the reaon, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add delay and run this method on a handler.

```
 pw.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.packButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 1000);  
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the button variable non static and instead call a method of your activity from your listener and in this method set the button visibility. Having the button as a static variable could mean that although it is non null the button isn't added to the activities view at the point when you call to set is visibility.

Comment: your answer suggest that the button can actually appear a little later then it should, and that causing the problem. But what is wrong with a button appearing a "long" time after the popup dismiss?

Comment: No, it suggests that you may be calling view methods before the view has been drawn

Comment: i removed the static reference, question edited. I also tried calling a function in main activity, does not work.

Comment: @user2162550 Where did you remove the static reference in the updated question? Have you reverted that?

Comment: the question does not say "static reference" now.

Comment: @user2162550 The packbutton is static, so that you have accessed the packbutton as MainActivity.packbutton. Try to change the packbutton to non-static. I guess that Stephen coming to tell you this only.

Comment: MainActivity is not a class, its an instance of a class.